# how to test Load Balancer with Sticky Session

Tags: jmeter, jsessionid, elastic-load-balancer, sticky-session

I'm new to load balancer and Sticky Session. My understanding of Sticky session is that all request of one instance will be served via only one service( please correct me if I'm wrong).

I have a requirement to test the working of sticky session with load balancer. After some finding on google I have come across with a plan which is sending multiple request(using JMeter) to Load Balancer with more than one instance and to trace the IP address that is responding for each instance( which should be unique).

Please help me by validating the above plan or suggest me if any other ways is there to test.

Thank you with Regards,
Manikandan

Comment: What have you done, share the test plan

Comment: I have not started doing the JMeter script, Please validate my approach of doing test on Sticky session by sending request with multiple instances and checking whether the response is obtained only from single server (one server for each instances throughout the session)

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter